# PHP $_POST array empty after form submit on safari using Yii framework

Tags: php, safari

Code works on every browser except Safari.

I have a form that has a `target="_blank"` attribute. When the form is submitted, the $_POST array is empty when using Safari (checked by using a `Yii::log(print_r($_POST,true));`) HOWEVER,if you ctrl + click the submit button (Safari's shortcut for opening links in new windows) then the page loads as expected.

Anyone run into something like this before ? solutions?

Let me add that when the `target="blank"` is not present, the code also works.

Comment: Either don't submit to a new window, or don't use safari. ^^ (Though, I'm pretty sure this is a problem/feature of safari and unrelated to php or the framework. ^^)

Comment: is $_POST empty with other browsers?

Comment: no, everything works in other browsers. I just fixed this though by first opening a window with javascript and then submitting the form to that window. safari doesn't like the _blank for some reason